# Axios request returning an error in React js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I want to display the list of products in a webPage but I am getting an error.
I am using the async/await method on the axios.

The code:

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get("/api/products");
      setProducts(data);
    };
    fetchProducts();
  }, []);
```

I have installed **cors** and set the **proxy** as well in the front-end side package.json file but still getting an error like following:

[image]

Comment: Where is your baseURL
and cros orign is server side issue not frontend

Comment: http://localhost:5000/api/products ---> Server side @PiyushJain

Comment: are you using axios.create() in another file .

Comment: No it is the only file where I am using axios

Comment: soluation in front of you. 
your server port is 5000 and you calling 3000 
that's why this error shown

Comment: No, I don't think this is the issue because React server is running on port 3000 and backend is running on port 5000

Comment: Your backend server is running on port 5000, but your request is going to port 3000. Piyush Jain already mentioned the error, fix it

Comment: as you said this is the only file you using axios then you have to define proper url in axios
axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/product")